# (Python) Cannot find existing file with regex, Path.glob, and known substring

Tags: python, pandas, linux, filesystems, pathlib

I am trying to find a file with a given ID, this ID contains numbers, letters, and underscores. I am iterating through a list of the IDs, finding their location based of a given directory (which is accurate), and using `sub_tree.glob(".*"+ID+".*")` to find any file names which contain the ID. Currently glob returns no files even though I can both verify that A the files in question exist and B the regex will return the file (I confirmed this with `find -regex patternGivenAbove)`. Can anyone help me? This is on linux btw (running remotely via SSH on windows through a jupyter notebook).

I've tried a few things, at the moment I am running the ID through `re.escape(ID)` to ensure no weird characters are causing issues. I've confirmed that ID and the subpath are accurate and the file exists. Here is the code as of now:

```
def rename_matching_ids(df,path,dataset,subset,view):
    pl_path = pathlib.Path(path)

    for id in df['id']:
        sub_path = df[df['id'] == id]['file_dir'].values
        newName = "1_" + dataset + "_" + subset + "_" + view + "_" + id
        img_sub_path = pl_path.joinpath(sub_path[0])
       
        regex =  r".*" + re.escape(id) + r".*"
        matching_files = img_sub_path.glob(regex)

        if(matching_files):
            for file in matching_files:
                print(file)
                pl_patient = img_sub_path / file
                if pl_patient.exists():
                    
                    newPath = img_sub_path / newName
                    print("Renaming:" + pl_patient.as_posix() + "-> " + newPath.as_posix()) 
                    os.rename(pl_patient, newPath)
                else:
                    print("Error: Cannot find file- " + pl_patient.as_posix())
        else:
            print("Error: Cannot find ID " + id)
```

I will note that the `if(matching_files)` always returns true even if the iteration doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`glob()` uses wildcard patterns, not regular expressions. And to recurse into subdirectories like `find` does, you have to start the pattern with `**/`.

```
pat = f"**/*{id}*"
matching_files = img_sub_path.glob(pat)
```